# Type-safe named fields in haskell ADTs

Tags: haskell

There's a very common problem that is very easy to get into with haskell. Code-snippet that describes it is this:

```
data JobDescription = JobOne { n :: Int }
                    | JobTwo
                    | JobThree { n :: Int }
  deriving (Show, Eq)

taskOneWorker :: JobDescription -> IO ()
taskOneWorker t = do
    putStrLn $ "n: " ++ (show $ n t)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- this runs ok:
  taskOneWorker (JobOne 10)

  -- this fails at runtime:
  -- taskOneWorker JobTwo

  -- this works, but we didn't want it to:
  -- taskOneWorker (JobThree 10)
```

I described this problem and it's possible solutions in this article: https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/k_bx/playing-with-datakinds

Here, on StackOverflow, I'd like to ask you -- what are the best solutions to this problem, using which tools and what documentation?

Comment: IMO, the only problem here is that Haskell allows you to declare field accessors at all in a multi-field ADT. I consider that abuse of record syntax, just don't do it and there is no problem.

Comment: @leftaroundabout sure. The problem with my production code I have is that field-accessors are there already, and use quite heavily everywhere. So I want to continue having field-accessors (to not do crazy refactoring), but still get type-safety.

Comment: Just define a new function `nOne :: JobDescription -> Int` that only works for `JobOne`s.

Comment: @TomEllis and in case of getting JobTwo -- would it throw an exception? Hehe. // actually, that's the actual problem, some of my code *already* works only with JobOne, while got JobTwo and "crashed"

Comment: Oh, I thought you *wanted* `taskOneWorker JobTwo` to crash, so I just copied the behaviour.  If you *don't* want it to crash you should use `Prism`s.

Comment: @TomEllis sure, prisms are an option to get total accessors, but that's really an overkill to get maybes all the time, considering that you almost always get one big function per task which work with one concrete task (from which you extract fields multiple times). So I'd go with type-based approach (also, I need to deal with existing code, and that'd help).

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a `Prism`.  The `Prism` `_JobOne` represents the `Int` value that lives inside the `JobOne` constructor.  In `taskOneWorker` we look it up using `^?`.  Either the value `t` is indeed a `JobOne` constructor and its argument is return in the `Just`, or it is not a `JobOne` constructor and we get back a `Nothing`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens

data JobDescription = JobOne { n :: Int }
                    | JobTwo
                    | JobThree { n :: Int }
  deriving (Show, Eq)
$(makePrisms ''JobDescription)

taskOneWorker :: JobDescription -> IO ()
taskOneWorker t = do
  case t ^? _JobOne of
    Just n  -> putStrLn $ "n: " ++ show n
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a JobOne"
               -- Or 'return ()' if you want to ignore these cases

main :: IO ()
main = do
  taskOneWorker (JobOne 10)
  taskOneWorker JobTwo
  taskOneWorker (JobThree 10)

-- *Main> main
-- n: 10
-- Not a JobOne
-- Not a JobOne
```

Comment: This seems as a poor option to me, in case when taskOneWorker is clearly considered to work with exactly JobOne (and not JobTwo or JobThree) this leads taskOneWorker to have more boilerplate and less type-safety than solution from link in original post.

Answer (score -1):

yeah; using lenses like you have and abstracting the "n" thing into some sort of "JobData" seems not too bad to me (maybe even good.)

Comment: Well, it lets you avoid run-time crashes with minimal effort (no need for DataKinds) for sure, but still would be nice to limit parameters via types when it makes sense.